# devexpress mapcontrol - disable layer animation

Tags: wpf, devexpress, devexpress-wpf

I'm creating a `VectorLayer` in code behind to display a path travelled by a vehicle. But adding a layer to `MapControl` uses some kind of animation. Path does not immediately show up, it takes a second or two. Is there a way to disable this animation?

```
    MapPolyline path = CreatePath(); // setting points, color, thichness, etc...
    VectorLayer layer = new VectorLayer() { }; 
    layer.Data = new ObservableCollection<MapItem>() { path };
    mapControl.Layers.Insert( 0, layer );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out by myself. Setting the property `UseSprings` of the `MapControl` to `False` solved my problem. It disables all animations on the `MapControl`

```
    <dxm:MapControl UseSprings="False">
    ...
    </dxm:MapControl>
```